# Explaining Unity Sprite-Default Shader

Tags: unity, shaders

I would like to know why we would use alpha blending in that shader for just rendering a sprite, which is just a texture ? 
What is tint color ?
Why we multiply the alpha value by the color here ?

```
fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord) * IN.color; // why ?
c.rgb *= c.a; // why ?
Shader "Sprites/Default"
{
    Properties
    {
        [PerRendererData] _MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color ("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        [MaterialToggle] PixelSnap ("Pixel snap", Float) = 0
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        { 
            "Queue"="Transparent" 
            "IgnoreProjector"="True" 
            "RenderType"="Transparent" 
            "PreviewType"="Plane"
            "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="True"
        }

        Cull Off
        Lighting Off
        ZWrite Off
        Fog { Mode Off }
        Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha

        Pass
        {
        CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma multi_compile DUMMY PIXELSNAP_ON
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata_t
            {
                float4 vertex   : POSITION;
                float4 color    : COLOR;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
                fixed4 color    : COLOR;
                half2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            fixed4 _Color;

            v2f vert(appdata_t IN)
            {
                v2f OUT;
                OUT.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, IN.vertex);
                OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;
                OUT.color = IN.color * _Color;
                #ifdef PIXELSNAP_ON
                OUT.vertex = UnityPixelSnap (OUT.vertex);
                #endif

                return OUT;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex;

            fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord) * IN.color;
                c.rgb *= c.a;
                return c;
            }
        ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tints are used often in sprites. This helps change the colour very quickly without having to change the texture itself, or make a copy. Alpha blending may be used when drawing sprites. For example, you'll probably want alpha blending for 2D particle effects.

Comment: So If I just want to draw a 2D GUI Texture(an image) is it ok to remove the tint and the alpha blending from that shader ?

Comment: Yeah, if you don't want these features, I'd assume so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "tint" color is a color that gets modulated (multiplied) with the texture color. This color is used with sprites for effects like making the player sprite blink red when hit by an enemy. To do so, you could set the tint to red when the player gets hit and leave it red for a couple frames, them restore it to white. Do that repeatedly for a few seconds and you'd have a blink effect for your sprite.

Multiplying the texture's `RGB` with the `A` could be used to give you a fade in/out effect. The alpha channel in the RGBA is a normalized value in the [0,1] range, so if you were to multiply the RGB with an alpha of say 0.2, you would get a very dark sprite. Multiply it by 1 and you will get the texture color as it is. You could get this same effect by multiplying the color with a back/white tint, BTW.

Finally, alpha blending should be on to ensure that sprites that have transparent areas get drawn properly. Most sprites have transparencies, so blending is required, otherwise the transparencies would be draw as if they where filled with some color. If you are sure you don't have transparencies in your sprites, then alpha blending could be safely disabled.